# Any Drools example for update listener

Tags: java, drools

With reference to this [Drools java update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169715/drools-java-update)

I found that updatelisteners exists which can be used to fire rules when any facts(objects) are updated via java code, but couldn't find any example for it

Please help to find/share helpful example for this

Thanks
Chakri

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the documentation? 
Check the 4.7.2.1.6. @propertyChangeSupport section

http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.Beta2/drools-expert-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e4780